# R: How to subtract each observation from a number

Tags: r, variables, subset

I have a dataframe (SCWB) from 2001 with 5500 observations (people).
The variable YRBIRTH captures the individuals' year of birth. 
I would like to create a new variable called AGE -->  "AGE = 2001 - YRBIRTH"
I can't seem to figure out how to code this variable into R - so far I have:

```r
SCWB$AGE <- lapply(SCWB, transform, YRBIRTH = 2001 - YRBIRTH)
```

And an error message:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "SCWB$YrBrth <- lapply(transform, SCWB$YRBIRTH ="

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'SCWB' is a `data.frame`, we can directly apply `transform` on the column 'YRBIRTH' instead of a loop with `lapply`

```
SCWB <- transform(SCWB, YRBIRTH = 2001 - YRBIRTH)
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for!!